# Broken Bat File

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, runtime-error

So this code isn't my work, and truthfully I do not understand it, but if I can fix this bit of code around so it works, that'd be great.

```
@setlocal enableextensions
@cd /d "%~dp0"
del lastrecording.mp4
mklink lastrecording.mp4 %1
PAUSE
```

I'm getting the following errors.

```
del lastrecording.mp4
Access is Denied 
for delete function
```

As well

```
mklink lastrecording.mp4 %1
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
Creates symbolic link.
```

Comment: So do you pass this batch file an argument or something or what? Does the `lastrecording.mp4` named file exist in the same directory you have this batch file residing?

Comment: So the point of the batch file is to delete a file from the current directory then to grab the most recently created file in a directory that is just above this one copy paste into the folder and then rename.

Essentially it is a simple replay system for a program called OBS.

This is a link to the youtube of what exactly that batch file is attempting to accomplish. again thanks for the help. :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iuOOEL3rtjQ